# do syntactic sugar and assignment

Tags: haskell, monads

Assume this code:

```
g :: Maybe Int
g = do
  x <- Just 5  -- THIS LINE, `x` is plain Int
  Just x
```

is an alias for:

```
g = Just 5 >>= \x -> Just x
```

My question is, isn't that confusing that the assignment `x <- Just 5` leads to the fact that `x` is of type `Int` and not `Maybe Int`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Whether it's confusing depends on who you ask, i.e. it's completely subjective. Or is your question something different?

Comment: We can simplify `g = Just 5 >>= \x -> Just x` to `g = Just 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't confusing. Also if you extend your example just a step closer to a real world problem, you'll even see a reason to all this. E.g.:

```
g :: Maybe Int
g = do
  x <- Just 5  -- THIS LINE, `x` is plain Int
  Just (x + 3)
```

How would you solve this problem if `x` was still a `Maybe Int`?

I think [this tutorial](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html#monads) might help you a lot in understanding monads.

Comment: Nice tutorial! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you think `x :: Int` is confusing, you are mistaken. The real confusion here is that you perceive `x <- Just 5` as *assignment*. In order to assign anything, you first need to be able to extract the value. This is possible for some monads, but not all monads. For example, `Maybe a` stores just one value in it, so you can imagine `x <- Just 5` "extracts" a value from `Maybe Int`; but the analogy fails once you consider even just a list: `[a]`, where `x <- [1..5]` no longer has a direct correspondence to a assignment. This is also the reason why there is no function that extracts values from arbitrary monads - how do you "extract" a `Int` from a `[Int]`? how do you "extract" a `Int` from a `Cont a Int`?

You need to work through several examples to understand what it means to be a functor or a monad. It is better to think of `m Int` not as "a container with Int", but rather "`m` with some `Int`-ness in it". This is to say that it is some `m` that has behaviours specific to `m`, and behaviours specific to `Int`. The monadic operations must obey particular laws, so you can consistently modify "`m` with some `Int`-ness in it" to be, for example, "`m` with some `Char`-ness in it".

I think it is better to consider `<=<`, which is a "funny composition", rather than `>>=` or `<-`, which can be mistaken for "extraction of a value".

Comment: So, if `x <- Just 5` and `x :: Int`, what's the type of `x` in `x <- [1..5]`?

Comment: @Cartesius00, `x` is of type `Int`, but in this context it is not an assignment, at least, not exactly and certainly not in imperative way.